# Using Vaadin with Maven

Tags: maven, vaadin

In my project I have several Maven modules one of them consists of UI written in Vaaadin.

Everything seems fine but when I'm trying to run the project in Tomcat I receive an error in browser which indicates that Vaadin was not compiled.
Can anybody describe what I should do to force Vaadin compilation on mvn package of whole project or may be on mvn install on module with Vaadin?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vaadin addons you must compile them with GWT compiler and you must use compiled widgetset.

The best way is eclipse plugin. You can find it searching by google.

For using custom widgetset: https://vaadin.com/en_GB/book/vaadin6/-/page/gwt.usage.html (vaadin 6)

Comment: I wouldn't consider eclipse plugin to be the 'best way' to compile the widgetset, especially when the question is about using vaadin with _maven_. One reason people use maven is that you don't have to "search google" and do these things manually.

Comment: I wrote "search google" becouse SO didn't give permit for putting link more then one. The link is: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started

Answer (score 0):

I'll just assume you didn't mean to use the word "prevent". Do you have these plugins in your pom?

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
    <filesets>
        <fileset>
            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</directory>
        </fileset>
    </filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
    <!-- <runTarget>mobilemail</runTarget> -->
    <!-- We are doing "inplace" but into subdir VAADIN/widgetsets. This 
    way compatible with Vaadin eclipse plugin. -->
    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
    <hostedWebapp>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</hostedWebapp>
    <noServer>true</noServer>
    <!-- Remove draftCompile when project is ready -->
    <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
    <compileReport>true</compileReport>
    <style>OBF</style>
    <strict>true</strict>
    <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/</runTarget>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
    <execution>
        <configuration>
            <!-- if you don't specify any modules, the plugin will find them -->
            <!-- <modules> <module>com.vaadin.demo.mobilemail.gwt.ColorPickerWidgetSet</module> 
            </modules> -->
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>resources</goal>
            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
            <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Make sure you have defined `vaadin.plugin.version` variable to match with your Vaadin version and if you need to check anything else from the "original" Vaadin application pom, generate a fresh Vaadin application by calling:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application -DarchetypeVersion=7.0.5 -DgroupId=your.company -DartifactId=project-name -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=war
```

You can of course change the archetypeVersion to suit your needs.

If you DID mean to prevent the widgetset compilation, I guess it's enough that you comment out the `resources` and `compile` goals from the vaadin-maven-plugin. I'm not 100% sure about this because I only have done it in Vaadin 6 (..in which you need to comment out the same goals from the gwt-maven-plugin)